# Problema com SUDO "must be setuid root"

Tags: ubuntu, linux

Então, acho que o título é auto-explicativo. Sou iniciante no Linux, fui tentar instalar o Steroids (ambiente de testes para APP's híbridos) seguindo [esse tutorial](http://www.appgyver.com/steroids/getting_started) (o segundo, de instalação), e agora sempre que tento usar o SUDO aparece essa mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19306929/3029543

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse problema provavelmente ocorreu após você executar o comando abaixo ([**fonte**](https://muut.com/i/appgyver/steroids:consequences-of-chown-in-in)):

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` `npm -g bin`
```

Ao usar o comando `chown` com a opção `-R` você diz ao sistema para alterar o proprietário de arquivos e informações do grupo de modo recursivo, em seus subdiretórios e arquivos. O que certamente afetou o [`sudo`](http://www.uniriotec.br/~morganna/guia/sudo.html).

Para consertar isso você deve reinicializar o sistema e entrar em modo de recuperação para reverter esse processo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A partir do menu de inicialização, selecione o modo de recuperação, geralmente é a segunda opção de *boot*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de selecionar o modo de recuperação e esperar por todos os processos de arranque, será mostrado algumas opções. Neste caso, você deve inicializar escolher abrir um [*shell*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) como [*root*](http://www.uniriotec.br/~morganna/guia/root.html).

Em versões recentes do Ubuntu, o sistema de arquivos está montado como somente leitura, então você precisa digitar o seguinte comando para remontar como leitura e escrita, o que permitirá que você faça alterações:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Feito isso, você estará no terminal como superusuário, digite:

```
# mount --all
# chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
# chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Depois de executado os comandos acima, encerre a sessão:

```
exit
```

Isso o levará de volta para o menu de recuperação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Escolha para retomar uma inicialização normal. Em seguida, você deve ser capaz de usar o `sudo` novamente.

<sub>[`Fonte`](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo#recoverymode)</sub>

Comment: QMechanic73, Não consegui man. O primeiro comano executando com o `, remount /` processou algo. Depois tentei dar `remount /` mas não deu. Depois rodeu `adduser meuuser sudo` e foi avisado que já faço parte do grupo sudo.

Comment: @ropbla9 execute *mount -o rw,remount /* uma vez somente. Se nao der certo, execute "mount -o remount /". Se voce estiver usando a versao **12.04 (ou superior)** execute "adduser NomeDoUsuario sudo" se isso nao der certo execute "sudo usermod -a -G sudo NomeDoUsuario".

Comment: Eu to usando a versão mais recente do Elementary OS Luna

Comment: @ropbla9 Tem como comentar como você chamou o comando `chown` ao instalar o Steroids?

Comment: eu não lembro como fiz nada, cara.

Comment: eu fiz assim:

mount -o,remount / - OK > adduser myUser sudo (user ja faz parte do sudo) > sudo usermod -a -G sudo rop - OK. Mas ainda não funcionou.

Comment: esse funciona. Inclusive eu já tinha resolvido com essa mesma sequência que achei numa resposta na net. De toda forma sua resposta tá certa!

Answer (score 1):

Possivelmente você não configurou a senha do root, tenta fazer isso:

```
$ sudo passwd root
```

Digite a senha para o usuário root ai tente instalar os pacotes que você quer.

---

Caso não dê certo verifique as permissões do arquivo sudo

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
```

E posta ai

---

Certo, tente logar como root

```
$ su root
```

Se conseguir entrar digite os comandos

```
$ chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
$ chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Se você não conseguir vai ter que entrar em modo de recupeção e digitar esses dois comandos que passei.

Para entrar em modo de recuperação: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: AdirKuhn, ainda nd http://3.ii.gl/Lp4M2JsTM.png

Comment: Adir Kuhn, ainda não consegui cara. Exeuctei esses dois ultimos comandos pelo modo Recorey, ambos funcionaram, mas ainda nao consegui usar sudo.

Comment: Adir Kuhn, tentei entrar em su root logado no sistema normalmente e pede uma 'password', tento colocar a minha que configurei na instalação e não vai.